# Promisfy gzip stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream

I am trying to create a gzip stream which I can re-use elsewhere. Gzip works good to compress a stream of data but I wanted to refactor my code so I could seperate concerns. In doing so I ended up with the following. However, I can't utilised the returned stream.

```
const zlib = require('zlib');

function compress(stream) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const gzipStream = zlib.createGzip();

    gzipStream.on('end', () => {
      resolve(gzipStream);
    });

    gzipStream.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e);
    });

    stream.pipe(gzipStream);
  });
}
```

However I get empty output when I use the returned stream. E.g. I compress a 50mb file filled with 0's, and after using my new function, I get an empty file.

```
async function handler(req, res) {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream("./test_50m");
  const compressedStream = await compress(fileStream);
  
  compressedStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./test_50m_output"));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't utilised the returned stream"? That not how streams work.

Comment: @Marc I am trying to use gzipStream immediately afterwards by piping to another writeable stream to write to file or upload to s3 for example.

Comment: Note that the snippet cannot rely on the `end` event to be emitted before the gzip stream is piped to a writable sink. Thus, `await compress()` might never resolve if the source file is larger than the combined read buffer of the intermediate stream middlewares. I recommend taking a look at `stream.pipeline()`. It might be a more direct approach to achieving the same functionality.